# URL rewriting: Rewrite index.html to /home-page search friendly text

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

All my website pages are named as index.html under their relevant directories.
For e.g:

```
www.mydomain.com
```

takes me to

```
 www.mydomain.com/index.html
```

And clicking on about-us page, the URL comes as

```
www.mydomain.com/about-us/index.html
```

(where about-us is the name of the directory)

How do I rewrite these URLs using .htaccess so that my site is more search friendly? Like:
When user goes to
`www.mydomain.com` it should rewrite the URL to

```
www.mydomain.com/my-home-page
```

and when user goes to

```
www.mydomain.com/about-us/index.html
```

it should rewrite the URL to

```
www.mydomain.com/about-us/About-Me-Page
```

Comment: Why would you need to create additional structure? You already have `about-us`. It's redundant to make it `www.mydomain.com/about-us/About-Me-Page` Just rename the folder to About-me-page then. The index filename should not be shown anyway when the user goes to `www.mydomain.com/about-us` so it's already SEF and anyone who has used the internet knows the main domain is usually the homepage of the site

Comment: I wanted to do that because I want to make my site search friendly in terms of SEO. The client site is http://canyonstudios.com.pk/ and I want to rewrite the URL of the home page to be http://canyonstudios.com.pk/best-dentist-services
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /my-home-Page.html [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/index.html$ /about-us/about-me-page.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! but if I use the first rule you stated, I have to manually change all the files having index.html names to meaning-full-name.html pages. Is there any way to avoid manually changing all the index.html files and still have the user friendly URLs at address bar?